# vlookup + if command

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am a newbee excel user and need assistance in compiling an Excel formula. I have basic IF functions down and Vlookups. I need assistance in combining the 2.

I need the formula to read: if CELL L2 is a number then do a vlookup for that in sheet1!a2:b1048576 and display info, if it's TEXT then display info from L2.

Or I can reverse.. if is text then use L2 info, if isNUMBER then do vlookup in blah blah

```
=IF($L2="","",IF(ISNUMBER(L2),L2,VLOOKUP(VALUE($L2),'Inv-PO cross-ref'!$A$2:$B$1048576,2,FALSE)))

=IF($L2="","",IF(ISTEXT(L2),L2,VLOOKUP(VALUE($L2),'Inv-PO cross-ref'!$A$2:$B$1048576,2,FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> `=IF($L2="","",IF(ISNUMBER(L2),L2,(VLOOKUP(VALUE($L2),'Inv-PO cross-ref'!$A$2:$B$1048576,2,FALSE))))`

- `IF(ISNUMBER(L2),L2,(VLOOKUP...` - you're doing the opposite what you've described.
  "if CELL L2 is a number then do a vlookup"
  => first parameter of `IF` should be the `VLOOKUP`
- `VLOOKUP(VALUE($L2)` - as L2 is a number you don't need to convert it again

so your formula:
`=IF($L2="","",IF(ISNUMBER(L2),VLOOKUP(L2,'Inv-PO cross-ref'!$A$2:$B$1048576,2,FALSE),L2))`